# Cannot set property 'id' of undefined when trying to get a object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I am having an issue when I try to get a specified user from Firebase, Firestore.

```
export class TaskService {
  tasksCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Task>;
  taskDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Task>;
  tasks: Observable<Task[]>;
  task: Observable<Task>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.tasksCollection = this.afs.collection('tasks', ref => ref.orderBy('title', 'asc'));
  }

  getTask(id: string): Observable<Task> {
    this.taskDoc = this.afs.doc<Task>(`clients/${id}`);
    this.task = this.taskDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(action => {
      if (action.payload.exists === false) {
        return null;
      } else {
        const data = action.payload.data() as Task;
        data.id = action.payload.id;
        return data;
      }
    }));

    return this.task;
  }

}
```

And this is my `Component.ts` file

```
export class TaskDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  task: Task;
  hasHours = false;
  showHoursOnUpdate: false;

  constructor(
    private taskService: TaskService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    // Get id from url
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    // Get client
    this.taskService.getTask(this.id).subscribe(task => {
      if (task != null) {
        if (task.hours > 0) {
          this.hasHours = true;
        }
      }
      this.task = task;
    });
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(this.task);
  }

}
```

The result for id is good.
But the result for object (task) is undefined.

**P.S**
I also have functions for getting all the users and adding a new user, so if that's relevant please let me know in the comments

Comment: Your console log is going to fire before the task is defined.

Comment: It should be in the subscribe block to really know what task is

Comment: I tried that too. But it's returning 'null'

Comment: try doing a console.log of action in your service, before if (action.payload.exists === false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line of code

> this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;

In this case `id` is not a table column but it's your document id by Firestore

[Here an example of firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iic93.png)

So your `Id` in this case is the red one and not the blue one.